# How to catch a snapshot (reponse) and render it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, request, snapshot

I am using create-react-app. And if you observe the following function I made to request data from firebase:

```
request = (id) => {        
    firebaseDB.ref(`Majors/${id}`).once('value')
    .then((snapshot)=>{           
        this.setState({
            data: snapshot.val()
        })
    })
 }
```

as seen above I have updated the *state* with the value in snapshot.val.

now in the same component, I use this.state.data
like this

```
 showCourses(){        
    this.state.data.Courses.map((item,i)=>(
        <div key={i}>
           asd
        </div>           
    ))        
 }
```

and it throws back an error saying 'this.state.data.Courses are not defined'
because the response(snapshot) is not **back with data yet** and the state hasn't been updated.

i tried to add a conditional like this:

```
showCourses(){
    if (this.state.data.Courses){
        return(this.state.data.Courses.map((item,i)=>(
        <div key={i}>
           asd
        </div>)))
    }
}
```

the error goes away but it does not render!

I assume the question is: What is the mechanism used to catch, update state and rerender component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of `this` used in `request` function, `this` is not binded properly with the element. try using `function () {}` syntax and then add this immediately after making the function:

```
request = request.bind(/* your element */);
```

i hope it helped :)